# buying bitcoins with debit cards that are not mine

Tags: buy-bitcoins, traceability, bitcoin-credit-card, debitcard

I have a couple of cards that are not mine, I have all of the card holders info and card info. I want to purchase bitcoins and then transfer them to other wallets.

I have a couple of friendswho want to purchase bitcoin, I would buy the bitcoins for everyone, that is why I have all of their card and personal info.
I wanted to use a single wallet (mine) and then transfer the funds to each of my friends preferred wallets.
However I will have no control over where they spend it or how they use it.

Can I personally be traced?

Comment: I think you must increase the your question because it lets think of a scam

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have a couple of friends and myself who want to purchase bitcoin, I would buy the bitcoins for everyone, that is why I have all of their card and personal info.
I wanted to use a single wallet (mine) and then transfer the funds to each of my friends preferred wallets.
However I will have no control over where they spend it or how they use it.

Answer (score 5):

> I have a couple of friendswho want to purchase bitcoin, I would buy the bitcoins for everyone, that is why I have all of their card and personal info. I wanted to use a single wallet (mine) and then transfer the funds to each of my friends preferred wallets
>   Can I personally be traced?

First off, service recommendations are off-topic on this site, for more info see the [help centre](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help).

Next, I'm seeing a lot of red flags here:

You have some friends who want you to buy BTC for them, but **WHY** would they give you all of their debit card and personal info to do this? Normally if I wanted my friend to buy something for me, I would just give them the cash, or transfer it electronically, or whatever. I would NEVER just give someone full access to my banking information, so that they could buy Bitcoin (or whatever) with it. I find this circumstance extremely suspicious.

This, combined with the worry of being traced, really makes it look like you have some stolen cards that you are attempting to buy BTC with.

I suspect that any legitimate exchange you attempt to interact with will come to a similar conclusion, anti-fraud checks usually involve a cross-reference between the account holder and card holder names and addresses at least. Attempting to use a bunch of cards that aren't yours to make the purchase will likely set off a lot of fraud warnings in any system.

If you are in fact acting legitimately, then it should be no problem having your friends transfer you money, you can make the purchase on an account under your name, and then disseminate the coins to your friends as appropriate. If you are concerned about your friends using the Bitcoin in some illicit way that could be traced back to you, then it may be worth reconsidering your offer to purchase the coins in the first place. For more info on Bitcoin privacy and fungibility, [this article is quite comprehensive.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Privacy)

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know I could buy them with cash, Ive never bought or had bitcoins in any way, I'm guessing I have alot to learn before trying to buy for myself or for anyone else.